# How to avoid IllegalStateException with MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I have a stop button and a play button.  When I click the play button, the audio plays fine and when I press stop, the audio stops.  However, if I accidently hit the stop button twice in a row, an IllegalStateException gets thrown and force closes.  How can I keep this force close from happening.  Essentially what I want is that if someone accidently hits the stop button twice, the program does nothing.  Here is the code:

```
                private MediaPlayer mp;


                 @Override
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.alphabet);

                 Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.e_1100);
               mp.start();
               mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                }
        });
        }
});

       Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

             stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
             mp.stop();
             mp.release();

                } 
        else if (mp.isPlaying() == false) {

                   // What do I put here???

        }
        }
});
    }
```

}

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace of the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        }
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
```